# Integral over smooth, closed curve of vector field

Tags: calculus, analysis

Why doesn't vector field $v:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^3}$ given by $v(x,y,z)=(x,\cos y,e^z)$ does not meet $$\int_{\gamma} \langle {v\frac{\gamma'}{\|\gamma'\|}\rangle}\ d\sigma_1=0$$for every smooth, closed curve $\gamma$? How do I even understand the intergrand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be the line integral around the curve parameterized as $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{\gamma}(t).$  The integrand looks like the dot product of $\mathbf{v}$ and the unit tangent vector. The curl of $\mathbf{v}$ is identically zero. By Stokes' theorem the integral should be $0$.

Comment: It does meet this condition then, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.